# Bluetooth phone shows up on ubuntu settings gui, but not on hcitool

Tags: bluetooth

My phone (OPPO Reno2 Z) shows up on the Ubuntu (20.04) Settings/Bluetooth gui, and I can pair with it. However, it does not show up with  `sudo hcitool -i hci0 lescan`. All other devices near me show up in both places. I want to run [this](https://github.com/efeuentertainment/BLE-continuous-RSSI-scan) script to do continuous RSSI capture, but it does not find the device when I give it the bluetooth MAC address, which I assume is related to the reason hcitool doesn't see it either. The script works with the MAC addresses of other devices near me. Am I using hcitool correctly? How can I get it to detect my phone?